# Doubt on the proof of inequality involving a Linear Transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

There's one exercise on Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds that he uses all the time in the text. The exercise is: prove that if $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear, then there's some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $|T(h)|\leq M|h|$.

My attempt to prove his was the following: consider the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\{e_i\}$ and the canonical bases of $\mathbb{R}^m$ $\{f_j$}. Then if $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $h=\sum_{i=1}^{n} h^i e_i$ and for each $e_i$ we have $T(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ij}f_j$. This implies that:

$$T(h)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}h^iT(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}h^ia_{ij}\right)f_j$$

Now, using $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ the euclidean norm we find that:

$$|T(h)|^2=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}h^ia_{ij}\right)^2$$

Since this is a sum of positive numbers and since the square root function is always increasing this satisfies:

$$|T(h)| \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}h^ia_{ij}\right)$$

Now taking $M=\min\{a_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq n, \ 1 \leq j \leq m\}$ we have:

$$|T(h)|\leq M\sum_{i=1}^{n}h^i$$

Until there I'm fine, I just don't know how to conclude that this is equivalent as what's being purposed. If $h^i > 1$ for all $i$, it's obvious that $(h^i)^2>h^i$ and so the sum of all $h^i$ is less or equal than the sum of the squares. But if $0 < h^i < 1$ then we have $(h^i)^2<h^i$ so that this argument no longer holds.

Can someone give a help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that if ${e_i}$, $1 \leq i \leq n$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x = \lambda_1x_1+\ldots+\lambda_nx_n$ then $||x||\geq|\lambda_i|$ for all $i$. Thus, $|\lambda_1|+\ldots+|\lambda_n| \leq n||x||$.

Now set $M' := \max\{||T(e_1)||,\ldots,||T(e_n)||\}$ and $M := nM'$, then you have \begin{align}
       ||T(x)|| 
    =& ||T(\lambda_1e_1+\ldots+\lambda_ne_e)||
    =  ||\lambda_1T(e_1)+\ldots+\lambda_nT(e_n)|| \\
 \leq& |\lambda_1|\cdot||T(e_1)|| +\ldots+ |\lambda_1|\cdot||T(e_1)||
 \leq  M'(|\lambda_1|+\ldots+|\lambda_n|)
 \leq  M'n||x|| \\
 \leq&  M||x|| \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: Note that this crucially depends on there being only finitely many dimensions. Which any such proof must, since linear operators in infinite-dimensional spaces may, in fact, be unbounded.

Comment: In fact, you should be able to show that if the standard matrix of $T$ is $A=[a_{ij}]$, then $M=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}$ always works. This is somewhat comforting, as you can think of $A$ as a point in $R^{mn}$, this is the Euclidean length. For this, I suggest thinking about Cauchy-Schwarz and the *row vector* interpretation of matrix multiplication.